# Change button content depending on List count

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

That's my button:

```
<Button Content="Start" x:Name="StartButton" Click="StartButtonClick" IsEnabled="{Binding Items.Count}" Width="120"/>
```

and I've a List in my ViewModel:

```
List<String> Items;
```

- If Items.Count is 0 or 1, the content of the button should be "Start"
- If Items.Count is > 1 the content of the button should be "Stop"

How can I do that?

Comment: What if `Items` is null?

Comment: Then it should be disabled with the button content Start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind content of the button to another propety on your view model that would compute the message from list count.
ViewModel part

```
public string ButtonContent {get{return (Items.Count<=1) ? "Start" : "Stop";}}
```

and WPF binding

```
<Button Content={Binding ButtonContent, Mode=TwoWay } />
```

Comment: might want to add the binding syntax for content. just a suggestion.

Comment: The content of Button will not change when collection is modified with such approach.

Comment: This solution with a NotifyPropertyChanged in the Items property works well

Answer (score 3):

First of all you will need to use `ObservableCollection<string>` for your items as it will notify when items count was changed.

After that the following XAML will change button content based on items count:

```
<Button>
   <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
              <Setter Property="Content" Value="Stop"/>
              <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
                       <Setter Property="Content" Value="Start"/>
                   </DataTrigger>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count}" Value="1">
                       <Setter Property="Content" Value="Start"/>
                   </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try to Bind method to content, that will returns you needed value, something like this:

```
public string GetStartButtonContent()
{
     return Items.Count() > 1 ? "Stop" : "Start";
}
```

I don't know WPF and don't know how to bind the method to content...

Answer (score -1):

You should add id to button if there are more than one buttons and reference id prededing with #. You will need to include jquery for it to work.
Pseudo code goes like:

```
$('body').on('click','Button',function(){
if(condition to check count>0)
    $('Button').attr('content','Start');
else 
 $('Button').attr('content','Stop');

})
```

Comment: The question was about WPF but not Java Script.